# Bitcoin verify a single block in python

Tags: python, blockchain, bitcoin

Currently i try to verify the Bitcoin Block 77504 by my own. But from the satoshi whitepaper it seems i have more questions than answer to do so.

First information from the previous block:

```
### What we know from last block ###
# height         = 77503
# id             = 00000000000447829abff59b3208a08ff28b3eb184b1298929abe6dd65c3578a
# version        = 1
# timestamp      = 1283325019
# bits           = 459874456
# nonce          = 1839166754
# difficulty     = 623.3869598689275
# merkle_root    = f18107935e8853011e477244241b5d786966495f8c59be46c92ac323c9cc8cde
# tx_count       = 6
# size           = 1438
# weight         = 5752
```

Then the information from the block i want to verify

```
### What we now want to mine ###
# height         = 77504
# id             = 00000000004582246e63ff7e0760c6f009e5ef5ce1eb5397be6f3eb9d698bda5
# version        = 1
# timestamp      = 1283326637
# bits           = 459874456
# nonce          = 191169021
# difficulty     = 623.3869598689275
# merkle_root    = 59c77dabd9f005c771b23b846c79c7741dc0e70d912f9470eace886b42a0d601
# tx_count       = 44
# size           = 11052
# weight         = 44208
# txids          = ["b899c55adb5a9604b72643c0f6cd5bf6c2447bb0fc035c50e13d2e471cbf5aa5","05180e3252c48a54d4d0abe9359621f54f3031fd318a812be96da0f13bfa8bf3","29d641bd4a5d4b01ceee1126af920513d52e088bad500fad1358c96962e25e28","40d52b5aa4be889739410f82f36c71fdda554b999fb14fc12aeab5bb2e6498cb","62d5e84500cc674a5172bea5755a223da974f90f614deb45c160478a8974419c","78de7a104617f58620ae9e7cf58bcd875d8043ee5046d93c9d69224c2ae39a1e","8831ad38deb23e1fbea6d376f1805aec194760b0f334a3c4b623aa0751445c9b","8a6bd0c2d74ea785d886bd6d87b6a4eb4cd35af5fb7ae3a364eb1f76b114c375","90d6da6a4b48e7330ae926cd00623fa8d94fd0a2b9a001475da22cbc49435ff9","d002da9953844c767cf7d42092b81e8c5bb03baf520d79028013fd3400bc8651","d1f8573148126e8d17641276f22ece33b8276311d93794ed2975ebb802b98fc8","d22ed765adba9c7f5fef19ff15cb89559b4148d571fcb40ee2889231ac1b8dea","f32b000adf9ab6d7a66593cb20cba4d3a3e0cbb3453608ce11a780fab532add5","32d2ff811677a8dbed4f317c9fcae4796b491bde944cca4a993734be787b4e79","4b806d44d9aff762601f21ad541c0e99a77d0a14b730774a2d7721dd094d9030","8c5258a8e3f60c9edfa55b86780a9832c8cd5f407dbe25948cd2fd87910ca4c4","bc4fcea23cd93bac13ab75bad8d23576be88a89e72f2c455932f096d6dd2a2da","ca5c53ef34ff5a2f816daf648c8dafb01680502c2c0c98b82b9527392f707e70","f9db6e9a62502dfe8057e7b1c0f3b8f145d354ee4e341233bfe8861fff143822","fc3730bbfa443558c677da6898f106ee7d5516b14e21bf369def7cb6a5bf6b8b","1cfa85d94ebfb9206ad49f421319a6ee99b339e4e8d292b866459bb742731d83","80fa7f38cc02b05b765675adba589d426e6122b1e8158726df0c55cf44c937eb","8c72683585901ff96edd14bde9c87ee91a9d54c187a15aa333e3d6b916399fd2","905e015afa4df7d9dc4a1a80a029e469258045fe9288071b16af49a2f458c2cb","bd8fab0ca0072cd230a4bb0a6efff5964756a023ca53d1f06c3fa22800fe044c","464280d62b8965255c286f1c4c5c457f594db64bdef1c8aaa7ddf776fc4d320e","625b8ec5af9ad2c1506aca8ad61670ce3acf7070fe5aabc2dec06dcda119503a","a2e06f6b0ea68cc2c9bf44d09e54832c830971961ed8ea5ec553918ab7eb48d2","a4de41f56f0970d9b1948f1e386a124860891d790f506c2e3bbe71dd289031d4","11475d2fbbc5e3aee2eff54aa9bf2f83d5f33fffce528cc9804f820e0f6a76e7","5dc019a6397c25d0e7db56f3ed2ccdc1db5642701224d56fb9ad1d1017279e7b","e5d1e0e5a2309cb07ec522a1eb56da5aa5e58ecaea6d49e278a52c1c24230dae","21d192ea46007dbeef7c9673ac158c0f9dbf80e0785380ae562a1fbb10430ae7","8fafe7a8168563c4c186d792b49fc0fa4368c6b2e5a1217f2f98b127ff1cdf87","d2410a45bcc0e4f5b7a8d84e730ffd9744e0dd0d9fb2d7e93fb71e590bf0f1fb","6103334a35171bc5a153b51dd7c94977c62822b1cec2fcac20ea9d0a959129d7","6551831774420989df2d9deeab196e14025f2e5fd502feb86dfc7ccedb917ce0","7c1a188e0c94c7d61aea1ebddb359f508c99fdd0e028887bbf3a3036a1b5bf8a","8b9c989cee69c107697b13aebd677879db48275c089ae206c85eb8db45acf50f","4195c5abf97adb2108de8aeee99cb751e2b4f9698607f60e326b9a67b9127a31","800b308f49fe86ff3323dd6240190212626d052a017dd1cad01540790604c00f","1d2fb37bab59d6f3f83f7596fde128a0b7b0f7ccd8fabc8d2a929923a268a847","8a8149d58791ace6cefd803021b4e870acca5b2c40e2e1415f423e6ec4333e32","7a1eb6b8ee1ff52648cd9a099c7658be53627732b226aa93f56d430c85a52991"]
```

I have prepared a small script that should calculate it for me but no matter what i am not able to get to the target hash 00000000004582246e63ff7e0760c6f009e5ef5ce1eb5397be6f3eb9d698bda5 to verify the block mined. What is also unclear to me where would one have to add his own Bitcoin wallet to get the reward of the transaction.

```
from hashlib import sha256

def SHA256(text):
    return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()

def mine(block_number, transactions, previous_hash, prefix_zeros):
    prefix_str = '0'*prefix_zeros
    text = str(block_number) + str(transactions) + str(previous_hash) + str(nonce_to_verify)
    new_hash = SHA256(text)
    if new_hash.startswith(prefix_str):
        print(f"Jipiiii! Successfully mined bitcoins with nonce value:{nonce_to_verify}")
        return new_hash
    else:
        new_hash = None
        return new_hash

### normally this is unknown, would be somethinge like range(0,100000000000), i just want to verify a block ###
nonce_to_verify = 191169021

 ### In what format are transactions presented ? ###
transactions = ["b899c55adb5a9604b72643c0f6cd5bf6c2447bb0fc035c50e13d2e471cbf5aa5","05180e3252c48a54d4d0abe9359621f54f3031fd318a812be96da0f13bfa8bf3","29d641bd4a5d4b01ceee1126af920513d52e088bad500fad1358c96962e25e28","40d52b5aa4be889739410f82f36c71fdda554b999fb14fc12aeab5bb2e6498cb","62d5e84500cc674a5172bea5755a223da974f90f614deb45c160478a8974419c","78de7a104617f58620ae9e7cf58bcd875d8043ee5046d93c9d69224c2ae39a1e","8831ad38deb23e1fbea6d376f1805aec194760b0f334a3c4b623aa0751445c9b","8a6bd0c2d74ea785d886bd6d87b6a4eb4cd35af5fb7ae3a364eb1f76b114c375","90d6da6a4b48e7330ae926cd00623fa8d94fd0a2b9a001475da22cbc49435ff9","d002da9953844c767cf7d42092b81e8c5bb03baf520d79028013fd3400bc8651","d1f8573148126e8d17641276f22ece33b8276311d93794ed2975ebb802b98fc8","d22ed765adba9c7f5fef19ff15cb89559b4148d571fcb40ee2889231ac1b8dea","f32b000adf9ab6d7a66593cb20cba4d3a3e0cbb3453608ce11a780fab532add5","32d2ff811677a8dbed4f317c9fcae4796b491bde944cca4a993734be787b4e79","4b806d44d9aff762601f21ad541c0e99a77d0a14b730774a2d7721dd094d9030","8c5258a8e3f60c9edfa55b86780a9832c8cd5f407dbe25948cd2fd87910ca4c4","bc4fcea23cd93bac13ab75bad8d23576be88a89e72f2c455932f096d6dd2a2da","ca5c53ef34ff5a2f816daf648c8dafb01680502c2c0c98b82b9527392f707e70","f9db6e9a62502dfe8057e7b1c0f3b8f145d354ee4e341233bfe8861fff143822","fc3730bbfa443558c677da6898f106ee7d5516b14e21bf369def7cb6a5bf6b8b","1cfa85d94ebfb9206ad49f421319a6ee99b339e4e8d292b866459bb742731d83","80fa7f38cc02b05b765675adba589d426e6122b1e8158726df0c55cf44c937eb","8c72683585901ff96edd14bde9c87ee91a9d54c187a15aa333e3d6b916399fd2","905e015afa4df7d9dc4a1a80a029e469258045fe9288071b16af49a2f458c2cb","bd8fab0ca0072cd230a4bb0a6efff5964756a023ca53d1f06c3fa22800fe044c","464280d62b8965255c286f1c4c5c457f594db64bdef1c8aaa7ddf776fc4d320e","625b8ec5af9ad2c1506aca8ad61670ce3acf7070fe5aabc2dec06dcda119503a","a2e06f6b0ea68cc2c9bf44d09e54832c830971961ed8ea5ec553918ab7eb48d2","a4de41f56f0970d9b1948f1e386a124860891d790f506c2e3bbe71dd289031d4","11475d2fbbc5e3aee2eff54aa9bf2f83d5f33fffce528cc9804f820e0f6a76e7","5dc019a6397c25d0e7db56f3ed2ccdc1db5642701224d56fb9ad1d1017279e7b","e5d1e0e5a2309cb07ec522a1eb56da5aa5e58ecaea6d49e278a52c1c24230dae","21d192ea46007dbeef7c9673ac158c0f9dbf80e0785380ae562a1fbb10430ae7","8fafe7a8168563c4c186d792b49fc0fa4368c6b2e5a1217f2f98b127ff1cdf87","d2410a45bcc0e4f5b7a8d84e730ffd9744e0dd0d9fb2d7e93fb71e590bf0f1fb","6103334a35171bc5a153b51dd7c94977c62822b1cec2fcac20ea9d0a959129d7","6551831774420989df2d9deeab196e14025f2e5fd502feb86dfc7ccedb917ce0","7c1a188e0c94c7d61aea1ebddb359f508c99fdd0e028887bbf3a3036a1b5bf8a","8b9c989cee69c107697b13aebd677879db48275c089ae206c85eb8db45acf50f","4195c5abf97adb2108de8aeee99cb751e2b4f9698607f60e326b9a67b9127a31","800b308f49fe86ff3323dd6240190212626d052a017dd1cad01540790604c00f","1d2fb37bab59d6f3f83f7596fde128a0b7b0f7ccd8fabc8d2a929923a268a847","8a8149d58791ace6cefd803021b4e870acca5b2c40e2e1415f423e6ec4333e32","7a1eb6b8ee1ff52648cd9a099c7658be53627732b226aa93f56d430c85a52991"]

### Just a check of 5 leading zeros... but why the difficulty 623.3869598689275 how to get to the 11 zeros? ###
difficulty=11

### Last Block (77503) found ###
lastfoundblock = "00000000000447829abff59b3208a08ff28b3eb184b1298929abe6dd65c3578a"


print("start mining")
new_hash = mine(77504,transactions,lastfoundblock, difficulty)
print("finnished mining.")
print(f"Found block is: {new_hash} should be the same as 00000000004582246e63ff7e0760c6f009e5ef5ce1eb5397be6f3eb9d698bda5")
```

Help would be appreciated so that i can verify a single block. Already pointing in the right directions would be appreciated so that i can solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As no one was able to answer it... here is the code to verify a block's nonce:

```
import hashlib, struct, binascii
from time import time

def get_target_str(bits):
    # https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty
    exp = bits >> 24
    mant = bits & 0xffffff
    target_hexstr = '%064x' % (mant * (1<<(8*(exp - 3))))
    print(f'T: {target_hexstr}')
    
    target_str = bytes.fromhex(target_hexstr)
    return target_str

def verify_nonce(version, prev_block, mrkl_root, 
               timestamp, bits_difficulty,nonce):
    
    target_str = get_target_str(bits_difficulty)
    header = ( struct.pack("<L", version) + 
              bytes.fromhex(prev_block)[::-1] +
              bytes.fromhex(mrkl_root)[::-1] +
              struct.pack("<LLL", timestamp, bits_difficulty, nonce))
    hash_result = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header).digest()).digest()

    return bytes.hex(hash_result[::-1])
    #nonce += 1


test1_version = 0x3fff0000
test1_prev_block = "0000000000000000000140ac4688aea45aacbe7caf6aaca46f16acd93e1064c3"
test1_merkle_root = "422458fced12693312058f6ee4ada19f6df8b29d8cac425c12f4722e0dc4aafd"
test1_timestamp = 0x5E664C76
test1_bits_diff = 0x17110119
test1_nonce1 = 538463288 #(0x20184C38)
test1_block_hash = "0000000000000000000d493c3c1b91c8059c6b0838e7e68fbcf8f8382606b82c"
test1_calc_block_hash = verify_nonce(test1_version,
                                     test1_prev_block,
                                     test1_merkle_root,
                                     test1_timestamp,
                                     test1_bits_diff,
                                     test1_nonce1)
print(f'S: {test1_block_hash}')
print(f'R: {test1_calc_block_hash}')
if test1_block_hash == test1_calc_block_hash:
    print("hashing is correct")
```

Thanks to https://github.com/razvancazacu/bitcoin-mining-crypto

Comment: Which block number is this for?

Comment: How did you get the timestamp value?

Comment: @KrisKrause 620953

Comment: lovely answer - straight to the point with further reference to source github project. nice!

Comment: This block is 620954 not 620953